# Include a menu in a Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-button

I want to insert a menu with one item into a linear layout. The idea is to have three buttons. One on the top right side of the Action Bar and the rest centered in a linear layout.

I have two files: content_tienda.xml (the linear layout) and menu_tienda.xml.

I want to include the first file into the second. How can I do it?

The code:

content_tienda.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btcomercio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btoferta"
        android:textColor="#f9f9f9"
        android:background="@drawable/boton_shape"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btoferta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/btcomercio"
        android:textColor="#f9f9f9"
        android:background="@drawable/boton_shape"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

menu_tienda.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item
    android:id="@+id/btsalir"
    android:title="@string/btsalir"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="0">
  </item>

</menu>
```

I tried to type in the menu_tienda.xml file the line

```
<include layout="@layout/content_tienda"
```

but buttons int the linear layout are not displayed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Menus are special items, not normal layouts. Menus are intended to be used within the activity menu system / toolbars and have to be inflated with a `MenuInflater`. You **cannot** include normal layouts in the menu xml declaration.

What you probably want to do is to create a custom `ToolBar` with your menu options, and your first layout to the left / right.